# Oracle 5 APEX - How to display address's on google maps

Tags: javascript, sql, google-maps, plsql, oracle-apex

Can anyone tell me how to display a list of address's on a google map with APEX?

The address's are currently stored in APP_CUSTOMERS table

```
  select cust_street_address1||', '||cust_city geoloc
  from   app_customers
  where  cust_street_address1 is not null
  order by customer_id;
```

Output

```
45020 Aviation Drive, Sterling
6000 North Terminal Parkway, Atlanta
1 Harborside Drive, East Boston
10000 West OHare, Chicago
Hangar Center, Flushing
```

Answer (score 1):

you may take a look to the following document as begining. you can add one address to map with this sample

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/integrating-apex-with-google-maps-169532.pdf

but this is mostly a google maps api question, you need to check the api documentation of google for adding multiple points to map

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/